# How to tell which component generated DOM node?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to tell which component generated a specific DOM node?, e.g.

```html
<CustomDiv>a</CustomDiv>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

`CustomDiv` is a just a wrapper that generates `<div />` element.

In DOM, these are represented as:

```html
<div data-reactid=".0.0.$/=11">a</div>
<div data-reactid=".0.0.$/=12">b</div>
<div data-reactid=".0.0.$/=13">c</div>
```

Is there a way to tell which of the DOM nodes have been generated by `CustomDiv` component?

Context:

I have a `DecoratorComponent` that wraps the `render` method of the component that it decorates. `DecoratorComponent` then modifies the resulting DOM.

```html
let Foo;

Foo = class extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>
            <SomeOtherComponent />
            {['a', 'b', 'c'].map((letter) => { return <p>{letter}</p> })}
        </div>;
    }
};

Foo = DecoratorComponent(Foo);
```

However, `DecoratorComponent` must modify DOM only thats produced by the target component, i.e. it should exclude the output of `SomeOtherComponent`.

I need to find a way to distinguish DOM that has been dynamically generated within the component (`{['a', 'b', 'c'].map((letter) => { return <p>{letter}</p> })}` in this example) and DOM thats generated by another component within the `Foo` component.

Comment: I do not believe what you are trying to do is something that is supported by react. There are no differences between the nodes created by mapping over `['a','b','c']` and `<SomeOtherComponent/>`, other than metadata like `displayName`. Could you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve, and maybe we could take a crack at solving it in a way that is more canonical to react?

Comment: Am I to understand that you have different components writing to the same parts of the DOM? Can you elaborate a little bit on why that's occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to inspect which DOM nodes have been rendered by which React component.

In addition, look into [`./src/renderers/dom/client/ReactMount.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.6/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactMount.js), which is the `react-dom` `Object` used to manage DOM nodes and their relation to React components. Note that `data-reactid` attribute is referred to as `ATTR_NAME` in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The data about which component rendered what *can* be found by digging into the React component instance internals, but you said you want to take a DOM node and figure out which React component rendered it, and this is a bit harder.

Do you really need to manipulate the DOM *after* React flushes it, or are you content to modify the React element (that gets returned from the JSX/`React.createElement` call) *before* rendering to the DOM happens? Either way, intercepting `render` yourself allows you to inspect the element and do what you want with it. Since child composite components don't get expanded into real DOM nodes until later, you'll only get the ones you care about.

Here's an example of a decorator that will add a property to every single element rendered by the given class:

```
function recursiveAddProps(elem, extraProps) {
  if (!elem) return;
  if (typeof elem === "string") {
    // strings get turned into spans
    return React.createElement("span", extraProps, elem);
  }

  const props = elem.props || {};
  const newChildren = React.Children.map(props.children, child =>
    recursiveAddProps(child, extraProps)
  )
  return React.cloneElement(elem, extraProps, newChildren);
}

function DecoratorComponent(klass) {
  const oldRender = klass.prototype.render;
  klass.prototype.render = function() {
    const elem = oldRender.apply(this, arguments);
    const name = this.constructor.displayName || this.constructor.name;
    return recursiveAddProps(elem, {
      className: "myOverriddenClass" // this will set className on every element
    });
  };

  return klass;
}
```

Using these components

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div>Hi!</div>
        <SomeOtherComponent />
        {['a', 'b', 'c'].map(letter => <div>{letter}</div> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Foo = DecoratorComponent(Foo);

class SomeOtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>Other</li>
        <li>Component</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

the code results in the DOM:

```
<div class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0">
  <div class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=10">
    <span class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=10.$/=10">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <ul data-reactid=".0.$/=11">
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.0">Some</li>
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.1">Other</li>
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.2">Component</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=20">
    <span class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=20.$/=10">a</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=21">
    <span class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=21.$/=10">b</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=22">
    <span class="myOverriddenClass" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=22.$/=10">c</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the class was added to every element *except* those rendered by `SomeOtherComponent` — the `ul` and `li`s.

If you wanted to set some special attribute on the DOM nodes so that you could identify whether or not the `Foo` component rendered it, you can specify a `data-` attribute and React will flush it to the DOM.

```
<div data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0">
  <div data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=10">
    <span data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=10.$/=10">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <ul data-reactid=".0.$/=11">
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.0">Some</li>
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.1">Other</li>
    <li data-reactid=".0.$/=11.2">Component</li>
  </ul>
  <div data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=20">
    <span data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=20.$/=10">a</span>
  </div>
  <div data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=21">
    <span data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=21.$/=10">b</span>
  </div>
  <div data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=22">
    <span data-rendered-by="Foo" data-reactid=".0.$/=12=22.$/=10">c</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here every DOM node has a `data-rendered-by="Foo"` attribute, allowing you to tell from the DOM alone that the node was rendered by `Foo`.

[Here's a working example](https://jsbin.com/tuliqu/edit?js,output) on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/tuliqu/edit?js,output

---

This is a pretty powerful abstraction which *may* allow you to do what you want without even touching the DOM; for example, in React CSS Modules, the DOM isn't touched — [the components are simply extended and render is overridden](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/blob/ca261d1a03f7c39c3e2ed2f8f45efb4e0997d3dc/src/extendReactClass.js#L17).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to avoid manipulating the DOM directly. It is possible with some precautions but it will likely decrease performance and might introduce hard to find bugs. Let me suggest some ideas to solve your task in a react space.

Let's start from simplest one. I guess you tried to do something like this:

```
const Foo = (props) => ( 
  <div>
    <SomeOtherComponent />
    {['a', 'b', 'c'].map((letter) => { return <Decorator><p>{letter}</p></Decorator> })}
  </div>
);
```

If you need to manipulate a list elements in one shot - you can wrap them this way:

```
const Foo = (props) => ( 
  <Decorator>
    <SomeOtherComponent />
    {['a', 'b', 'c'].map((letter) => { return <p>{letter}</p> })}
  </Decorator>
);
```

Decorator component will have access to child react elements. We can for example make bold everything excluding instance of SomeOtherComponent

```
const Decorator = (props) => (
  <div>
    { React.Children.toArray(props.children).map(child => 
        child.type === SomeOtherComponent ? child : <b key={child.key}>{child}</b>
    )}
  </div>  
);
```

If you want to go further and decide which decorator to use somewhere closer to the root of the app, you can simply pass Decorator component as a prop

```
<Foo decorator={Bolderator}/>

const Foo = ({decorator: Decorator}) => (
  <Decorator>
    <SomeOtherComponent />
    {['a', 'b', 'c'].map((letter) => { return <p>{letter}</p> })}
  </Decorator>
);
```

Comment: The implementation exists in real life in a popular project. There are no observable performance implications. https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules

Answer (score 0):

*Your question seems to be confusing some terms, so I'll first need to clarify how I understand it.*

> I have a `DecoratorComponent` that wraps the `render` method of the component that it decorates. `DecoratorComponent` then modifies the resulting DOM.

Directly decorating the `render` method and "modifying the resulting DOM" are two very different things. The `render` method doesn't return a DOM fragment, it produces a [`ReactElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements). Deciding whether a `ReactElement` denotes a DOM element or a React component is (in most cases) pretty easy - its `type` is a `String` in the former case and something else (a `Function` or `Class`) in the latter.

```
function decorateRender(render) {
  const el = render();
  el.props.children = React.Children.map(
    el.props.children,
    (child, idx) => (typeof child.type === 'string')
      ? <div className="wrapper">{child}</div>
      : child
  );
  return el;
}
```

If, however, you're not directly decorating `render` and you indeed are trying to modify the resulting, mounted DOM, there is, by default, no way to link the DOM elements back to their producers. In development environment, you could try to h4ck React internals and find the link (see [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)), but in production environment there isn't any back-link. DOM is only a product, the magic happens before, in React's "virtual DOM". Of course you could always extend `React.Component` to tag the elements with a custom data attribute on render.